# MS-Access Report Textbox Control Source Parameter

Tags: ms-access

I have a textbox on an access report where the current control source is a formula to return the number of days (last day) in the current month.

I would like to modify the formula so the user can input the month they would like to run the report.

My current control source is: `=DatePart("d",DateSerial(Year(#3/1/2020#),Month(#3/1/2020#)+1,0))`

I tried: `=DatePart("d",DateSerial(Year([Enter Date]),Month([Enter Date])+1,0))`

but the textbox is displaying #Type!

Comment: Cannot provoke popup input prompt from ControlSource.

Comment: Is there another way to have a user select the month they would like to run report for?

Comment: Enter to textbox (with or without date picker), select from combobox list, InputBox() function. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html